# how display particular values from json array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have some doubts in displaying values from the ajax objects. I need to display names in select box by using ajax. I do not know where i did the mistake.how can i change my code.please anyone help me.Thank you in advance.

**My javascript code:**

```
function getClient() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var client = JSON.parse(message);
            console.log(Object.keys(client));


            document.forms["project_form"]["Project_cid"].innerHTML='<select class="form-control" maxlength="100" name="Project[cid]" id="Project_cid"><option value=Select>'+Object.keys(client)+'</option></select>'

        }
    }
    var url = "/pms_pro/index.php/client/list";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

when i use alert(message), it will display like below,

```
[{"cid":"1","name":"suresh","address":"Chennai"},{"cid":"2","name":"Ramesh","address":"Namakkal"},{"cid":"3","name":"Vignesh","address":"Trichy"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('Project_cid');

// remove existing options
select.innerHTML = '';

// add the new options
var option, i;
for (i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = client[i].name;
    option.value = client[i].cid;
    select.add(option);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ilia choly.. i got it